# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7

Tags: java, node.js, maven, ant

I need help. I got the following error. 
I have googled around but cannot find any solution.

O/S Window: 7 (64-bit) 
Java: java version "1.6.0_45"

Command: mvn clean package -DskipTests

```
[exec] npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
[exec] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[exec] npm
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] Shopping Project .................................. SUCCESS [0.937s]
[INFO] Shopping Integration .............................. SUCCESS [2.020s]
[INFO] Shopping Job ...................................... SUCCESS [1.050s]
[INFO] Shopping Web Layer ................................ SUCCESS [33.822s]
[INFO] Shopping WAR ...................................... FAILURE [31.418s]
[INFO] Shopping DB Files ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:12.071s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 30 13:54:41 EEST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 85M/725M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.7:
run (1) on project Shoppingwar: An Ant BuildException has occured: exec returned
: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<exec dir="C:\training\Shopping\Shoppingwar" executab
le="cmd" failonerror="true" inputstring="yes" osfamily="windows">... @ 7:121 in
C:\training\Shopping\Shoppingwar\target\antrun\build-main.xml
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: If you want us to help you must provide more details such as the entire error message and your pom. Otherwise you make it too hard for us to help you and you run a big risk that you won't get any help.

Comment: Just looks related to that "cmd" command you launch inside the Ant build file, so see there what can be the issue, by debugging/adding logging to the Ant execution .